# Increase length of checksum

Tags: java, encryption, random

```
SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(2048, rand);       
KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
System.out.println(keyPair.toString());
```

I've been testing this code that generates random number. But it gives me same length 7 character string for 1024 and 2048 bit initialization. Is there any way to increase random number upto 16-20 character string minimum?

Ref. book : Cryptographic libraries for developers by Ed Moyle and Diana Kelly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of your snippet is something like `java.security.KeyPair@9e53ed`. This is not the key itself, it is just an identification of the KeyPair object. To inspect the Key you may use the `getPublic` and `getPrivate` methods.

Comment: What this string meaning? Could you please explain a bit more about it?

Comment: @guptavaibhav it is the output of the default `toString` method inherited from `Object`. The class name followed by `@` and the hash code of the instance.